# UseEffect afecta a otro useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy trabajando en react usando hooks, uso useEffect para hacer un primer llamado a la API y otro para llamar a la API cada 80 segundos con ayuda de setinterval, al ser una pantalla que muestra muchos datos necesitaba hacer un autoscroll para ello use un tercer useEffect para manejar el tiempo pero esta causando que los llamados a la API se hagan cada segundo lo que esta generando problemas de rendimiento.

¿Como puedo hacer para que el useEffect del autoscroll no afecte a los otros dos useEffect?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import  axios  from 'axios';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { animateScroll as scroll } from 'react-scroll';
import {
  createMuiTheme,
  responsiveFontSizes,
  MuiThemeProvider,
  Typography
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },

  grid: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
  },
}));

let theme = createMuiTheme();
theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);

export default function Registros() { 

  const [datos, setDatos]=useState([]);
  const [autoScroll, setAutoScroll] = useState(true);
  const [top, setTop] = useState(false);
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const classes = useStyles();

const goTop = () => {
     
    const windowHeight = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    const body = document.body;
    const html = document.documentElement;
    const docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight,  html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
    const windowBottom = windowHeight + window.pageYOffset;

    if (windowBottom >= docHeight && step >1 ) {
       setTop(true)       
    } 
};
  const getDatos = async () => {
    try{
       return await  axios.get(`localhost:xxxx/api/datos`)        
          .then(function(response){             
             return response;
          }).then(function(response) {
             setDatos(response.data.data);
          })       
          .catch(function(error) { 

             console.log('error catch', (error))
          });
     }catch(error) { 
       console.log('error en datos', error)
    }
 } 

useEffect(() => {
    getDatos();
    const interval = setInterval(getDatos, 80000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);

  useEffect( () => {
    if (autoScroll){
       const timer = setInterval(() => {
          setStep(step+1)
         
          if (top===false){
             scroll.scrollMore(25);
          }
          else{
           
             window.scrollTo({
                top: 0,
                behavior: "smooth"
             });
             setTop(false);
          }
       }, 1000);
 
       goTop();

       return () => clearInterval(timer);
       }
 },[autoScroll,step]);  


 const rfiltrados = datos && datos.filter(r=>r.grupo===2)

 return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Grid container spacing={0} >
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        Nombre
      </Grid>  
    <Grid item xs={4}>
        Departamento
      </Grid>  
    <Grid item xs={4}>
        Rendimiento
      </Grid> 
    </Grid>
    {rfiltrados.map(row => (
    <Grid container spacing={0} > 
     <Grid item xs={4}>
      {row.Nombre}
     </Grid>
     <Grid item xs={4}>
      {row.Departamento}
     </Grid>
     <Grid item xs={4}>
      {row.Rendimiento}
     </Grid>   
  </Grid>
  ))}
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  </div>
);
}
```

Comment: intenta agregar una o varias dependencias a useEffect como segundo parámetro, por ejemplo useEffect( ( ) => ... callback...  ,  [autoscroll, top, ...]). Esto hace que el callback se active al cambiar una de estas dependencias.

Comment: Disculpa me podrías explicar mejor tu idea, al useEffect le tengo que pasar como parametros  los estados de autscroll y top?

Comment: Si, cuando le pasas un segundo parámetro a useEffect, solo llamará a la función callback en caso cambie el valor del parámetro (se les llama dependencias). Por ejemplo, si colocas a autoscroll como dependencia de useEffect, solamente se activará  la función cuando cambie el valor de autoscroll, de esta manera los otros useEffect no lo afectarán. Aquí te dejo el link de la documentación : https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Comment: @davidbug  agregue las dependencias pero sigue llamando al api cada segundo [step,autoScroll]);

Comment: Porque necesitas añadirle las dependencias `[autoScroll,step]` al segundo `useEffect`?. Como te ha respondido el compañero de abajo solo hará el rerender cada vez que cambie la variable creando nuevos timers. Toda la logica del segundo `useEffect` la puedes meter en otro `useEffect` como el primero. Osea el timer se inicialize cuando se monta el componente.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos useEffect que serán ejecutados cuando se monte el componente
¿Puedes combinar estas dos lógicas y mostrarme bien tu componente?

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    const interval = setInterval(getDatos, 80000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

#### UPDATE:

Actualmente, tu segundo useEffect está así:

```
useEffect( () => {
    if (autoScroll){
       const timer = setInterval(() => {
          setStep(step+1)
         
          if (top===false){
             scroll.scrollMore(25);
          }
          else{
           
             window.scrollTo({
                top: 0,
                behavior: "smooth"
             });
             setTop(false);
          }
       }, 1000);
 
       goTop();

       return () => clearInterval(timer);
       }
 },[autoScroll,step]);
```

Esto hace que crearás un intervalo, que llamará a la función setStep(), cambiando el valor del estado/variable **step**; como el estado **step** se encuentra dentro del arreglo de dependencias, hará que se vuelva a ejecutar la función dentro del useEffect, instanciando un nuevo intervalo en cada que se actualice el estado **step**

La solución que te propongo es la siguiente: Remover **step** del arreglo de dependencias del useEffect, y llamar la función **setStep()** haciendo uso de **Functional setState** `setStep(step => step + 1);`

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (autoScroll){
            const timer = setInterval(() => {
                setStep(step => step + 1);
                
                if (!top) {
                    scroll.scrollMore(25);
                } 
                
                window.scrollTo({
                    top: 0,
                    behavior: "smooth"
                });

                setTop(false);
            }, 1000);
    
            goTop();

            return () => clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, [autoScroll]);
```

Espero te ayude de algo, pero estaré pendiente de todas formas

Comment: Si ya combine los dos useEffect pero sigue afectando al useEffect del scroll, ys puse el componente completo

Comment: También vi una función getData() en la línea 64 de tu código original, ten cuidado, no está definida

Comment: @SantiagoBetancur añadi los cambios que comentaste pero por alguna razon ademas de llamar el api cada segundo al hacer el console.log() me muestra los datos 4 veces, perdonde gatData es GetDatos ya lo corregi

Comment: ¿Cuál console.log?
Si el intervalo lo está haciendo cada segundo, entonces se puede decir que está bien(? haahah